# trigger only once on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I use the following code doing an action on scroll up or down.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
    } else {
      // upscroll code
      console.log("up");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

However, I only want to trigger it once.
Any idea of why the following version do not works?

Thanks !

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).one('scroll',function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
    } else {
      // upscroll code
      console.log("up");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? Do you mean it doesn't trigger, or it triggers multiple times?

Comment: Hello @toby thanks for the reply.
The second code do not works. While the first one triggers it multiple times, which is not what i am trying to do

Comment: what you mean by once ,  if you already scrolled at that postion doesn't scroll again ?

Comment: I only want to trigger the console.log("up") once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check wether your handler has been called or not - you should define a flag(`hasCalled` in this case):

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){

  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(st <= lastScrollTop) {
    console.log("up");
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;

});
```

Comment: I thought I tried that earlier, but I must have done a dummy mistake.

I slightly changed the code above, because the console log up do not triggers as the console log has triggered first (if scrolled down before up), but if i move hasCalled = true in the else, then it's fine, it only triggers once I scroll up

Thanks !

Comment: Bear in mind that this means your page will have an event firing every time someone scrolls. It might be better to remove the event listener when you have done handling it.

Comment: Hi Toby, I didnt think of that, but you are right. Any idea of how to remove that scroll listener? Once again, thanks everybody!

Comment: I have updated the answer - if it helped you - you can up/down vote